# How can I play a file audio (.mp3) when a button is clicked from a gui?

Tags: java, audio

I'm a beginner in Java and so far I learnt to do this:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame; // Importing JFrame
import javax.swing.JButton; // Importing JButton

public class GUI
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[JYT]"); // Naming a JFrame to frame + title [JYT]
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Exit on close
        frame.setSize(500,500); // Size of the frame
        frame.setVisible(true); // Setting to visible
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(218, 165, 32)); // Goldenrod color
        // Frame is set, time to add a button
        JButton button = new JButton();
        frame.add(button);
    }
}
```

Thing is I don't know how to display a button on the gui and how to make it play an mp3 when the button is clicked?

Are there any tutorials that will assist me?

Comment: the application is web o desktop?

Comment: Requests for tutorials and other off-site resources are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please modify your question to focus specifically on the problems you are having.